# Matrix with alternating direction of rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a square matrix that takes input `n` and create a matrix incrementing from 0 up to `n^2`

eg.

```
input: n = 2
output = [1 2
          4 3]


input = 4
output = [1  2  3  4
          8  7  6  5
          9  10 11 12
          16 15 14 13]
```

Comment: And you tried it using loops and are going to provide some code?

Comment: Hi Dan. I am extremely new to Matlab (I usually use python) I have searched online for a good amount of time for help with this and couldn't find anything that I would be able to use to try to solve this. Usually I would provide the code I used but I was so confused by this that I couldn't come up with any code at all! Sorry!

Comment: Come on, you could have tried using a simple `for`-loop or at least shown in your question that you had actually researched it first. Next time please post your attempted code, even if it's completely wrong. Even if you post a Python solution (which you'll probably find ports very easily to Matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 4;
output = reshape(1:n^2,n,n)';
output(2:2:end,:) = fliplr(output(2:2:end,:))
```